# Issue in adding title in head

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I get this error when trying to add the `Fragment`, `title` and `Head`. If I remove them the page display is fine. Couldn't find anything on this.

[image]

```js
import { Head } from "next/head";
import { Fragment } from "react";
import Layout from "../components/layout/Layout";

function HomePage() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Head>
        <title>Casselman Travel</title>
      </Head>
      <h1>Home Page</h1>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default HomePage;
```

Comment: Did the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in the first line, instead of `{Head}`, set `Head` without curly braces ;-) Here You can [read](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head) about, How to import properly `Head` from `Next.js` Best Regards !

---

This Line generate Your Error.

```
import { Head } from "next/head";
```

---

It Should be like that =>

```
import Head from "next/head";
import { Fragment } from "react";
import Layout from "../components/layout/Layout";

function HomePage() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Head>
        <title>Casselman Travel</title>
      </Head>
      <h1>Home Page</h1>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default HomePage;
```

*Checked now on Win10 & Ubuntu 20.04, VSCode 1.61.2, ("next": "11.1.2","react": "17.0.2")*